# Retrofit/GSON Is not parsing my JSON array of object

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I am getting null objects or GSON won't parse even tho I serialized. Here is the model of JSON data I am trying to parse:

```
[
{
    "parent": {
        "title": "Home"
    }
},
{
    "parent": {
        "title": "Learn",
        "children": [
            {
                "category": {
                    "title": "Computer Science",
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "title": "Database Management System",
                            "url": "taxonomy/term/57"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Programming Language",
                            "url": "taxonomy/term/118"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "category": {
                    "title": "General",
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "title": "Mathematics",
                            "url": "taxonomy/term/115"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

Here is the model class:

```
public class Parent {
@SerializedName("title")
private String title;
@SerializedName("children")
List<children> childrenList;

public List<children> getChildrenList() {
    return childrenList;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

public class Category{
    @SerializedName("title")
    String title;

    @SerializedName("url")
    String url;
}

public class children{
    @SerializedName("category")
    List<Category> categorylist;
}
}
```

Here is the service class:

```
public interface DynamicMenuService {
@POST("http://dev.myurl.com/somepath")
Call<List<Parent>> getMenuData();
}
```

I can confirm that the end point is returning the data (I added a logging interceptor to retrofit) every field is null. Including the title in the parent class is null but **the responce.body() in onResponce returns correct number of parent objects (that is the same number as the JSON parent objects)** the fields in the responce parent objects are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add a wrapper for your parent class, like this:

```
public class ParentsWrapper {
   @SerializeName("parent")
   private  Parent [] parents;
}
```

so your interface method should return a list of ParentsWapper objects, like so:

```
public interface DynamicMenuService {
    @POST("http://dev.myurl.com/somepath")
    Call<List<ParentsWrapper>> getMenuData();
}
```

You'll see that some of your classes are absolutely wrong, fix that too.

```
public class Parent
{
    @SerializeName("title")
    private String title;

    @SerializeName("children")
    private Children[] children;

    public String getTitle ()
    {
       return title;
    }

    public void setTitle (String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Children[] getChildren ()
    {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren (Children[] children)
    {
        this.children = children;
    }

}

public class Children
{
    @SerializeName("category")
    private Category category;

    public Category getCategory ()
    {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory (Category category)
    {
        this.category = category;
    }

}

public class Child
{
    @SerializeName("title")
    private String title;

    @SerializeName("url")
    private String url;

    public String getTitle ()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle (String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getUrl ()
    {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl (String url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }

}

public class Category
{
    @SerializeName("child")
    private Child[] child;

    @SerializeName("title")
    private String title;

    public Child[] getChild ()
    {
        return child;
    }

    public void setChild (Child[] child)
    {
        this.child = child;
    }

    public String getTitle ()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle (String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you I forgot to wrapt the parent object. Also, I completely overlooked the classes error since my priority is making the top level object work. Anyway, thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
use this for data modelling. Just paste your response from postman there and get your models.

Comment: Wow. Brilliant. Thanks.